# Running customized naive bayes classifier from command line in apache mahout

Tags: java, mahout

I have written my Java to invoke naive bayes classifier with the desired parameters.

I use eclipse with m2e plugin. My file is ZClassifier.java and resides at

`$MAHOUT_HOME/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/classifier/bayes.`

I am able to run it from eclipse, but I am not able to do it via command line. Kindly help me to run the same from the command line.

Comment: A little more information would be helpful: What's your command line, what's the error, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is a java classpath question, rather a mahout question.
Anyway, I think you can try this:

```
java -cp build/;[other jars if they not in your classpath] org.apache.mahout.classifier.bayes.ZClassifier [YOUR OWN PARAMS]
```

the "build" dir could be "bin" based on the version of eclipse.